# Возможно ли уменьшить код?

Tags: javascript, html

Вот код:

```
function fastmenu() 
{
    let menu = document.getElementById('actions');

    if (menu.style.opacity != 1)
    {
        return menu.style.opacity = 1;
    }

    menu.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

пытался сделать так

```
let menu = document.getElementById('actions').style.opacity;
```

и так:

```
let menu = document.getElementById('actions');
let opacity = menu.style.opacity;
```

Не работает. Ваш взгляд на то, почему это не работает и как это можно исправить?

Comment: Почему столько минусов, и ни одного комментария? Чем плох вопрос?

Comment: @Dmitry их было штук 20, их стерли

Comment: @Dmitry минусы - реакция участников на поведение автора вопроса в комментариях

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объекты копируются по ссылке, а примитивы по значению. В вашем первом случае вы в переменную `menu` копируете ссылку на объект, представляющий элемент DOM, изменяя свойства переменной `menu` вы изменяете и свойства этого элемента. Во втором и третьем случаях предположу, что вы скорее всего копируете в переменную значение свойства `opacity`, которое не является объектом, поэтому изменяя значение этой переменной, вы ни на что не влияете.

Короче можно записать через тернарный оператор, но сути это не изменит.

```
function fastmenu() 
{
    let menu = document.getElementById('actions');

    menu.style.opacity = menu.style.opacity != 1 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Бармен! Налейте-ка стакан кофейку за мой счет \`/

Comment: @Name, да что уж там - два гранта этому господину!